# Loading PDB symbols from symbol server's correct path?

Tags: visual-studio, qt-creator, symbols, pdb-files

In environment where we produce multiple builds in x intervals and store the resulting symbol files in server, is there a way to associate the correct path of the symbols for that particular build?

Comment: use symbol server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I had read the docs before but totally missed the id string in pdb file that does the matching if using symstore/symsrv. Thanks.  If you want the karma, put that in answer and I'll accept that one.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [symbol server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The association between a DLL/EXE and the PDB is done by the linker who adds a [GUID in the DLL/EXE and PDB to match both files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx) and now Debuggers or Profilers like WPR/WPA use this GUID to find the correct PDBs:

> When the linker generates .dll, executable, and PDB files, it stores
>   identical GUIDs in each file. The GUID is used by tools to determine
>   if a given PDB file matches a DLL or an executable file. If you alter
>   a DLL or an executable file—by using a resource editor or copy
>   protection encoding, or by altering its version information—the GUID
>   is updated and the debugger cannot load the PDB file. For this reason,
>   it's very important to avoid manipulating the DLL or executable file
>   after it is created by the linker.